p:tabView - remove tabChange on swipe
I am currently working on adjustments for the mobile page of an application I've developed and I am currently struggling with removing the change of a tab when swiping on a mobile phone (as defined in the touchstart EventListeners):

I've defined the tabView as follows:
<p:tabView id="tabView" touchable="false">

Is there anything I am missing in PrimeFaces to disable this behaviour?

What version of PrimeFaces.  I have verified touchable="false" disables it for me.
